# Problems with Salat methods in MongoDB: implicit view & not enough arguments

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, salat

I'm new with Salat,Casbah and MongoDB. When I've been trying to make a simple method to get all users from db,

```
 import DAL.Instances.User.{UserDAO, User}
    import com.novus.salat._
    import com.novus.salat.global._
    import com.novus.salat.annotations._
    import com.novus.salat.dao._
    import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
    import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection



    object UserRepository {

        def getAllUsers() = {

        val userList= UserDAO.find()

        userList.isEmpty match {
          case true => throw new Exception("None users in your db")
          case false => userList
        }
}
```

I faced with two errors:

```
Error:(29, 31) No implicit view available from Unit => com

.mongodb.DBObject.
        val userList= UserDAO.find()
                                  ^
    Error:(29, 31) not enough arguments for method find: (implicit evidence$2: Unit => com.mongodb.DBObject)com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor[DAL.Instances.User.User].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
    val userList= UserDAO.find()
                              ^
```

Here is my User code:

```
object User {
  case class User( _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId, name:String, age:Int)
  object UserDAO extends SalatDAO[User, ObjectId](collection = MongoConnection()("fulltestdb")("user"))

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of `Salat` you are using but if you look at the signature for `find` it'll give you a clue as to what the issue is:

```scala
def find[A <% DBObject](ref: A): SalatMongoCursor[ObjectType]
```

You need to call `find` with a parameter that has a [view bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html) so that this parameter may be viewed as a `DBObject`. This means that an implicit conversion from `A => DBObject` is expected to be in scope.

In your case you aren't passing any parameter. This is being treated as `Unit` and so the compiler tries to find an implicit conversion from `Unit => DBObject`. This can't be found so compilation fails.

To fix this you're best bet is to pass in an empty DBObject, you can achieve this with `MongoDBObject.empty` from [casbah](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.2/scaladoc/com/mongodb/casbah/commons/MongoDBObject$.html). You could add an implicit conversion from `Unit => MongoDBObject` but I'd probably lean towards making it explicit where possible.